# Dragon Ball Super anime and manga. Do elements and concepts which exists in one, also exists in the other?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Until now, we've seen some elements from the Dragon Ball Super anime which doesnt appear in the manga, and viceversa, some elements from the manga which doesnt exist in the anime. For example, in the anime we've seen the super saiyajin blue kaioken and the super saiyan rage transformation, but we havent seen those in the manga, and in the manga we've seen (recently added spoilers)

> Vegeta going super saiyan god (red) and a a technique where Vegeta is constantly switching from super saiyan god red and blue, red in repose and blue in brief moments of time when he attacks, to save energy and stamina

Do elements from one anime exists in the manga and viceversa? Or some elements are unique to each version and they wont appear in the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the manga as more logical and official material than the anime. As evidence, I will point out that the main idea of the manga and plot/detail is as requirement from Toriyama, while anime is just based on an outline of Toriyama, since Toei Animation considers it more like as child-oriented commercial animation. That's why some out of character moments and plot holes appear.